# Fat-Free-Framework - Prevent table name from being inserted into mapper object's virtual field

Tags: php, mysql, orm, fat-free-framework

I've been using the Fat-Free Framework recently, and things are going well (arguably better the longer I use it and leverage its components); however, I'm having difficulty with the ORM injecting the MySQL table name into a virtual field (used for lookup).

I know the SQL is good, and I know I could perform a second database call to retrieve the lookup field data, but since I've got things nearly working in virtual field format (and it's probably easiest to digest and debug)...

**Is there any way to prevent F3 from inserting the table name during SQL generation?**

Setup is easy...

```
class Bookmark extends \DB\SQL\Mapper
```

In the constructor, after the call to the parent constructor, I add my virtual fields...

```
$this->type_name = '
    SELECT CASE bookmark_type_id 
    WHEN 1 THEN \'Project\' 
    WHEN 2 THEN \'Member\'
    ELSE \'Unknown\' END
';
```

NOTE: **This works**, though **NOT** if I use an IF, then I get the table name injected into the IF clause -- after the first comma.

```
$this->description = '
    SELECT CASE bookmark_type_id 
    WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT p.title FROM projects p WHERE p.id = reference_id)
    WHEN 2 THEN (SELECT CONCAT_WS(\' \', m.first_name, m.last_name) FROM members m WHERE m.id = reference_id)
    ELSE \'Unknown\' END
';
```

NOTE: **This fails** with the table name inserted after the first comma (i.e. before m.first_name).

For clarity, this is the result (notice **`cm_bookmark`.**):

```
SELECT CASE bookmark_type_id 
    WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT p.title FROM projects p WHERE p.id = reference_id)
    WHEN 2 THEN (SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',`cm_bookmark`. m.first_name, m.last_name) AS FullName FROM members m WHERE m.id = reference_id)
    ELSE 'Unknown' END
) AS `description`
```

I get the feeling this is just another one of those "don't do that" situations, but any thoughts on how to achieve this in F3 would be appreciated.

(*Oddly, it's only after the first comma in the subquery. If the table name insertion was consistently clever, I'd expect to see it peppered in front of m.last_name too, but it isn't.*)

EDIT: It seems as though it's related to the second occurrence of something in parentheses. I've used CONCAT() in another virtual field call, and it works fine -- but it's the first (and only) use of parentheses in the field set up. If I remove the call to CONCAT_WS() and return a single field, the setup above works fine.

EDIT2: To clarify how the load is occurring, see below...

```
// database setup
// (DB_* set up in config.ini)
$db = new \DB\SQL($f3->get('DB_CONN'), $f3->get('DB_USER'), $f3->get('DB_PASS'));
$f3->set('DB', $db);

...

// Actual call
$db = \Base::instance()->get('DB');
$bookmark = new \CM\Models\Bookmark($db);
$bookmark->load_by_id($item['id']);

...

// in Bookmark Class (i.e. load_by_id)
$b->load(array('id=?', $id));
```

Comment: I tried your setup and it's working well. No problem with CONCAT_WS and no problem with multiple parentheses. Try to download the [edge](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core) version and see if it helps. Also, since this issue is about debugging your setup, I'd suggest to move this topic to the [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/f3-framework/).

Comment: I forgot to mention that F3 doesn't perform "table name insertion", so there's something else messing here. Maybe seeing the `load()` or `find()` call would help.

Comment: I've updated things to show the use in place. I'll have a look at edge and the forum (hopefully soon).

Comment: Forum post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/f3-framework/GjcseyRHQhA

Answer (score 0):

The only answer (to stay on this path) I have come up with so far is to create another virtual field and piece the 2 parts together later.

Not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The mapper does not allow such advanced capabilities, but I would suggest you use [Cortex](https://github.com/ikkez/F3-Sugar/tree/master-v3/Cortex) which luckily extends mapper so not much code change.

Below is an example:

```
Class Bookmark extends \DB\Cortex{
protected
    $db = 'DB', // From $f3->set('DB', $db); 
    $table = 'bookmarks'; // your table name
    /* You can also define these custom field preprocessors as a method within the class, named set_* or get_*, where * is the name of your field.*/
    public function get_desciption($value) {
        switch($this->bookmark_type_id){
             case "1":
             /*.....................Hope you get the drill*/
        }
    } 
}
```